# Realm: Index not defined for field

Tags: android, realm

I'm writing a RealmMigration, and after several different errors during that, I think I finally got it but now I'm getting io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Index not defined for field 'primaryKey'.

I saw something about needing to use table.addSearchIndex(), but even after adding that for each of my tables I'm still getting the exception.

Here is my Migration class.

Migration.java

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {

@Override
public long execute(Realm realm, long version) {
    Timber.i("Current database version: " + version);

    /**
     * Version 1:
     *      Task:
     *          Remove boolean field completed
     *          Remove Date field completedDate
     *      Transaction:
     *          Add int field type
     */
    if (version == 0) {
        // Transaction
        Table transactionTable = realm.getTable(Transaction.class);
        transactionTable.addColumn(ColumnType.INTEGER, "type");
        long transactionPrimaryKeyIndex = getIndexForProperty(transactionTable, "primaryKey");
        long transactionTitleIndex = getIndexForProperty(transactionTable, "title");
        long transactionPointsIndex = getIndexForProperty(transactionTable, "points");
        long transactionDateIndex = getIndexForProperty(transactionTable, "date");
        long transactionTypeIndex = getIndexForProperty(transactionTable, "type");

        for (int i = 0; i < transactionTable.size(); i++) {
            // Until now the only possible transaction was reward
            transactionTable.setLong(transactionTypeIndex, i, Transaction.TYPE_REWARD);
        }

        // Task
        Table taskTable = realm.getTable(Task.class);

        // Go through and create Transactions for each completed Task
        long taskPrimaryKeyIndex = getIndexForProperty(taskTable, "primaryKey");
        long taskCompletedIndex = getIndexForProperty(taskTable, "completed");
        long taskCompletedDateIndex = getIndexForProperty(taskTable, "completedDate");
        long taskTitleIndex = getIndexForProperty(taskTable, "title");
        long taskPointsIndex = getIndexForProperty(taskTable, "points");


        for (int i = 0; i < taskTable.size(); i++) {
            if (taskTable.getBoolean(taskCompletedIndex, i)) {
                transactionTable.addEmptyRowWithPrimaryKey(transactionTable.getLong(transactionPrimaryKeyIndex, transactionTable.size() - 1) + 1);
                long j = transactionTable.size() - 1; // The new row

                transactionTable.setString(transactionTitleIndex, j, taskTable.getString(taskTitleIndex, i));
                transactionTable.setLong(transactionPointsIndex, j, taskTable.getLong(taskPointsIndex, i));
                transactionTable.setDate(transactionDateIndex, j, taskTable.getDate(taskCompletedDateIndex, i));
                transactionTable.setLong(transactionTypeIndex, j, Transaction.TYPE_TASK);
            }
        }

        // Finally, remove the columns we don't need any more
        taskTable.removeColumn(getIndexForProperty(taskTable, "completed"));
        taskTable.removeColumn(getIndexForProperty(taskTable, "completedDate"));

        // https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.82.0/
        taskTable.addSearchIndex(taskPrimaryKeyIndex);
        transactionTable.addSearchIndex(transactionPrimaryKeyIndex);

        Table reminderTable = realm.getTable(Reminder.class);
        Table rewardTable = realm.getTable(Reward.class);
        reminderTable.addSearchIndex(getIndexForProperty(reminderTable, "primaryKey"));
        rewardTable.add(getIndexForProperty(rewardTable, "primaryKey"));

        version++;
    }

    return version;
}

private long getIndexForProperty(Table table, String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        if (table.getColumnName(i).equals(name)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

Task.java

```
public class Task extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long primaryKey;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private int points;
    private boolean hasReminders;
    private RealmList<Reminder> reminders;

    public static long getNextPrimaryKey(Realm realm) {
        RealmResults<Task> tasks = realm.where(Task.class).findAllSorted("primaryKey");
        if (tasks.size() == 0) return 0;
        return tasks.last().getPrimaryKey() + 1;
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Transaction.java

```
public class Transaction extends RealmObject {
    public static final int TYPE_TASK = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_REWARD = 1;

    @PrimaryKey
    private long primaryKey;
    private String title;
    private int points;
    private Date date;
    private int type;

    public static long getNextPrimaryKey(Realm realm) {
        if (realm != null) {
            RealmResults<Transaction> transactions = realm.where(Transaction.class).findAllSorted("primaryKey");
            if (transactions.size() == 0) return 0;
                return transactions.last().getPrimaryKey() + 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your model classes?

Comment: I have added the two classes involved in the Migration, the classes Reminder and Reward are pretty much the same as those, both with a long primary key.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I think it is because you are removing two columns in the task table before adding the index. That means that the index you calculated in the beginning is no longer valid.

Comment: Looks like that was it, everything is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are removing two columns in the task table before adding the index. That means that the index you calculated in the beginning is no longer valid.